# Simulating a keypress AND keyrelease in another application?

Tags: c#, keyboard, sendmessage

I need to interact with an external application running, and send specific keypresses & releases. I've tried to use the SendKeys class, but it does only half of the job, as the keypress is being sent with an immediate keyrelease to the external applications.

I need to be able to simulate a "key hold down" for the external app. I'm now trying to use the SendMessage thing, but for now it won't work at all :( and I don't even get errors.

Comment: I would think neither SendKeys nor SendMessage will meet your requirements. Sorry mate, I've no clue either.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172353/how-to-push-a-key-and-release-it-using-c/9509588

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, case solved. I actually installed VC++ to try the core keybd_event() function, and after it worked I was able to use it **wisely** in C#.

Here's the code, and surprisingly it's very simple. You'll need to add this using to your code to be able to import dll's: **using System.Runtime.InteropServices;**

This code will press and hold the '1' button for 3 secs, and then will release for 1 second and repeat the process.

(the code highlight got messed up :/, copy from 'namespace ...' to the last bracket '}')

```
public class Program 
{ 
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
    private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, 
        uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        while (true)
        {
            keybd_event((byte)0x31, (byte)0x02, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            keybd_event((byte)0x31, (byte)0x82, (uint)0x2, UIntPtr.Zero);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944(VS.85).aspx) to send [`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(VS.85).aspx) and [`WM_KEYUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646281(VS.85).aspx) ?

Edit

You would use it this way (I am writing in C++, but you can easily use [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/) and ..NET)

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,_T("Mywindow"));
PostMessage(hwnd,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_A,0);
```

Comment: Can you please show me a working piece of code? I'm struggling to find an answer for like 3 days now and nothing worked even remotely except for the SendKeys

Comment: I added a link to pinvoke.net where you can find the PInvoke headers for the given functions

Comment: Ok, I've tried to tweak your solution and to get it to work in C#, I've also got the headers from Pinvoke (I think!). It's still not working and I feel like I'm getting in to a recursion of things I don't get... Any chance of someone explaining why the SendMessage won't work, or a C# example of PostMessage?

Comment: Could you post the sample code that you have and a better description of what you see happen (or not) versus what you expect to happen?

Comment: For WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP to work you often have to traverse the component hiearchy to find the actual component to send them too. It is recommended to use SendInput instead although quite a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WSH Scripting Shell to do this:

```
var shell   = new WshShellClass();
var missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

shell.SendKeys("MOO!!!", ref missing);
```

All you need to do is add a COM reference to "Windows Scripting Host Object", version 1.0. Everything is in the namespace `IWshRuntimeLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

The official API is [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I'm struggling to find a working C# example for more than 3 days now... I would really appreciate one of those.

Comment: Googling C# "SendInput" got me this: http://blogs.msdn.com/robgruen/archive/2004/05/10/129221.aspx