# Powershell mouse scrolling script

Tags: powershell

There's SendKeys command for WshShell object which imitates pressing keys on keyboard. Is there a command which would imitate scrolling a mouse wheel?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of powershell command to scroll the mouse wheel, but you can embed a C# class in a powershell script/module and you can use C# to scroll a window.

"Basically", you need to use the Windows api `PostMessage` in `user32.dll` to send a `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message to the Window handle to make that window scroll. User32 is an "unmanaged" dll (part of Windows) and not a dotnet assembly so it requires special handling.

Have a read of these two links - between them they cover roughly what you would need to know to write a powershell function to fake scrolling the mouse of a window yourself:

- [Example of using c# to scroll a mouse wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203135/set-delta-in-a-wm-mousewheel-message-to-send-with-postmessage) - using DllImport to import "User32.dll" and calling PostMessage to send the window a WM_MOUSEWHEEL event.
- [Example of embedding a C# assembly in a powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190518/calling-keybd-event-in-user32-dll-from-powershell). Using `Add-Type` to create an inline c# assembly. This code is sending keyboard messages not mouse messages - but this is pretty similar to what you want to do.

Advanced warning - these are advanced topics and there are plenty of pitfalls using low level operating system functions. Good luck!